# screen record with input and output sound ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, recordmydesktop

I want to record my Skype calls with both input & output sounds and my screen. I tried `recordmydesktop` with `pulseAudio volume control` and `GNOME ALSA Mixer`. I tried answer given in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/250278/45805). It records either the input or the output, but not both. Also I don't want to route my input audio to output for this purpose, as it disturbs the conversation over Skype. I use ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/), which is paid application but really good. It probably would need to have Wine installed, which can emulate Windows programs.
Then there is [Bandicam](http://www.bandicam.com/), it is free-to-use but there is 10 minute limit until you buy it. At least was.

Fraps in my opinion is way easier to use, but Bandicam might have some better features.

Hope this helped you!

Comment: I'm a developer and only uses open source or free apps. I'm never gonna buy something like that even if I need to write some script to do that.