# Sound recording from built-in mic, not external mic

Tags: sound, windows, microphone

I'm new to Linux. I bought a Sony ECM-CS3 microphone which works OK on Windows. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm afraid it doesn't even recognize the input as a sound recorder device. My pc is a Lenovo U31 (which only has one input for in/out - if that's relevant).

If I run `pavucontrol` while audacity is recording on the background, it shows that the sound is being captured from the built-in microphone. Not from the Sony ECM.

I'd like to use the microphone on Linux since I wish to migrate entirely to Linux on the next few weeks.

Comment: Have you tried to change the input device from your sound setting? Don't you see it there?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I have not. On input devices there is only the built-in microphone showing up. I do have my Mic plugged in but it just doesn't recognize it.

Comment: The microphone plugs into your laptop with a 3.5mm plug which looks like a headphone jack, or does it use USB ? If so, are you sure you're really recording from the built in mic ? It's possible that it says that it's using the built in mic even when it's actually using an external mic plugged into the microphone jack - give the external mic a tap with your finger while recording to make sure.

Comment: I resolved this with the described in the following link: [enter link description here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250073/how-to-record-any-internal-sound-in-and-out-using-ubuntu-and-audacity)