# Audacity not showing pulse audio option

Tags: pulseaudio, audacity

Audacity not showing pulse audio option. I tried installing "alsa" but there is no such thing. I tried installing alsa plugins, but "make" does not work after configuration. I tried running pulse audio, but I get

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

It is a fresh ubuntu install

Comment: In a standard Ubuntu both ALSA, and Pulseaudio are already installed and running ([see also here](https://askubuntu.com/a/427036/3940)). Audacity uses ALSA as a host interface, and the `default` playback device which comes from PulseAudio. What is it that is not working for you?

Comment: "Audacity not showing pulse audio option" @Takkat

Comment: It does not show it with my installation too - but everything works as expected.

Comment: weird @Takkat i am trying to follow a walk thru for recording youtube etc. to audacity

Comment: [This should still work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250073/how-to-record-any-internal-sound-in-and-out-using-ubuntu-and-audacity) but design may have changed a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work by following [this tutorial](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_linux.html) in the official Audacity doc.  Primarily:

- Install `pavucontrol`
- Open *PulseAudio Volume Control*, select the *Recording* tab, then select *Monitor* in the *Capture from* dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry probably a bit late for you now but I have Audacity running on Ubuntu 20.04 with a Behringer UMC404HD using the following command line:
pasuspender -- audacity
both input and output works fine. Be aware there is a lot of low level clicking during the setup process but it does not seem to affect the results. It seems the other options offered by Ubuntu are not functional at this time.