# How to record from Mixer

Tags: 20.04, audio-recording, audacity

How to record from Mixer?

I want to record the audio such as youtube or other audio playing.

Dell 5755 Ubuntu 20.04

audacity-linux-3.1.3-x86_64.AppImage

ALSA
HD-Audio Generic:ALC3223 Analog (hw1,0)
Pulse
Default

Sound settings:
Input Device:
Headset Microphone-Built in Audio = ( unplug headphones, replug and choose MIC then can record voice through headphone speakers)

Microphone Built in Audio = (no audio at all from laptop but faintly can hear on playback my fingers hard tapping the laptop)

Internal Microphone Built in Audio  = (can hear audio but record outside noises)

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y pavucontrol
pavucontrol

While youtube is playing and audacity is recording I see under Recording:
ALSA plug-in [audacity]...from Built-in Audio Analog Stereo

Play back recording and zero from youtube and I just hear me typing and clicking the mouse.

Tried:
sudo apt-get install alsa alsa-tools.
Source: https://frameboxxindore.com/windows/how-do-i-install-alsamixer-on-ubuntu.html

How do I add myself to the mixer? Don't know how, didn't try.

Did a hard restart. Nothing changed.

arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

want to record audio such as youtube or other audio playing.

pactl list short sources;
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING

[How to record any internal sound in and out using Ubuntu and Audacity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250073/how-to-record-any-internal-sound-in-and-out-using-ubuntu-and-audacity/525110#525110)

pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1

total silence in recording but can hear audio in headphones from youtube

Now Audacity says  Pulse and Default only (!!)
HD-Audio Generic:ALC3223 Analog (hw1,0) is MISSING

HARD RESTART
HD-Audio Generic:ALC3223 Analog (hw1,0) is now back in Audacity along with Pulse and default.

I'm going to stop here before I truly screw up things and asking for help as to recording audio from audio streaming.

Comment: Related: [Recording phone calls in Ubuntu 20.04 - not just Skype](https://askubuntu.com/q/1316606)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record youtube sound or video you can use the **[downloadhelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/)** browser extention that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer using a different program found at
https://vitux.com/how-to-record-audio-in-ubuntu/

audio-recorder.

:):):):):)