# Audacity playback speed much too fast, on Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, audacity, playback

I just had a major issue with Audacity, on the first Ubuntu Maté distro. I was doing some sound work, and recording directly from microphones and audio monitors; but when I attempted to play back the sound, it was consistently done at an extremely high pace. Further experiments uncovered that even generated sound, like tweets, was playing back maybe 10x too fast—I could see it on the time bar.

Since I didn't really have time to mess around with it, I tried just uninstalling it, deleting all config files, and installing it from scratch. It works now, at least for the time being (thankfully!), but does anyone know what could have caused this? I don't really understand where the problem was coming from, so there's a good chance I'll see it again.

Thanks for all of your time and expertise!

Comment: Development releases are off-topic here, please [submit a bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) so that developers are aware of your problem...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem on lubuntu/xubuntu 14.04. I couldn't find anything that helps till I found this after long time of searching: http://bbb-solutions.blogspot.de/2014/11/audacity-playback-is-too-fast.html

Edit

```
pkexec gedit /usr/share/applications/audacity.desktop
```

and replace

```
Exec=audacity %F
```

with

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 audacity %U
```

Comment: If you run audacity from the terminal rather than the launcher or desktop, you can still use this solution. Just run `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 audacity` from the terminal.