# Capturing ONLY desktop audio with ffmpeg

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, ffmpeg

I want to know how can I only capture desktop audio (means no mic!).

I am using this command:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1360x768 -r 30 -i :0.0 -preset ultrafast ~/Videos/out.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
[x11grab @ 0x16051e0] device: :0.0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1360 height: 768
[x11grab @ 0x16051e0] shared memory extension found
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1444234613.435347, bitrate: 1002700 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1360x768, 1002700 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
File '/home/elderzz/Videos/out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] ^A
```

I can capture mic with another app, but I need the mic audio to be in a different file. I only want to capture desktop audio!

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i put the console output on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9GSZ1eTr

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## pavucontrol

[image]

1. Install `pavucontrol`.
2. Start recording with `ffmpeg` (see example commands below).
3. Start `pavucontrol`.
4. Go to the **Recording** tab and you'll find `ffmpeg` or `Lavf56.15.102` (or similar) listed there.
5. Change audio capture from **Internal Audio Analog Stereo** to **Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo**.

Now it should record system and application audio instead of the microphone.

This setting will be remembered. The next time you want to capture with `ffmpeg`, it will automatically start recording system audio. If you want to revert this, use `pavucontrol` again to change back to microphone input.

The text above was adapted from [HOWTO: Screencasting on Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8746719#post8746719).

## example ffmpeg commands

### audio only

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default output.wav
```

### with screen capture

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1360x768 -framerate 30 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mkv
```

Comment: Will this recording be lossless?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi No. `-crf 18` is lossy, and there is also loss due to RGB to YUV 4:2:0 colorspace conversion.

Comment: No I was talking about the audio only part.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Yes, the audio should be lossless.

Comment: How to stop the recording? `q` or `Ctrl-C` is not working.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi It should be working. Try `kill -s SIGINT $(pgrep ffmpeg)`.

Comment: If you do not want to switch the source manually, you can use the command `pactl list soruces` to figure out the internal name of the monitor source and then use `-f pulse -i NAME` instead of `default`, e.g. `-f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor` The exact name will differ from system to system.

Comment: @regnarg After I record using `-i  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor` (it is same for my system) when I play the output using mpv I get `Audio device underrun detected.` And there's no audio output (Played a song in the background)

Comment: Is there anyway that we can record system default output audio device on MacOS? I mean using commands or programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can also record to compressed MP3 (with a bit rate of your choice) such as:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k ouput.mp3
```