# How to stream desktop and audio with ffmpeg in youtube

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I found many answers on the subject, but no one works for me. Would you give me directions or working examples of how it works. It may be useful to other people in future

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://gist.github.com/laurenarcher/4644aacef51e734d33d5

Comment: Yes but this is for webcam stream. I search for desktop

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Choose audio

You can use pavucontrol to choose which audio source `ffmpeg` will record, such as "desktop" or microphone. This is explained in [Capturing ONLY desktop audio with `ffmpeg`](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/59378).

## 2. Encode

Now use `ffmpeg` to stream to YouTube:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default -c:v libx264 -preset fast -cfr 26 -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 5000k -g 60 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://youtube
```

- If your `ffmpeg` doesn't have `--enable-libpulse`, and therefore no pulse input device, you can try replacing `-f pulse -i default` with `-f alsa -i pulse` to use the ALSA input device instead.
- Don't just copy and paste the example: you'll need to choose an appropriate `-maxrate` and `-bufsize`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for Streaming Sites](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) for more info.