# How to run OBS studio on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server, graphics, gpu-driver, tightvncserver, obs-studio

I have installed obs-studio on my Ubuntu server 16.04 but when I try to open it gives me this

> error: failed to initialize video. your GPU may not be supported or
>   your graphics drivers need to be updated.

I have installed a xfce4 desktop and I use it through tightvnc.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run it on the local system rather than through TightVNC? What's the output of  `sudo lshw -C display` on the server? on the system you are accessing the server with? Please [edit] this info into your post along with anything else you think might be useful after reviewing [this.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be why do you want to do this. what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: No I am actually installing it on a dedicated vps i have bought from somewhere so i dont have the physical access to the system. I want to stream videos on youtube through OBS. I am accessing the server with ssh

Comment: lshw -C display command shows the following output                                                           "*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:1f:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0

Comment: When adding requested information to a question please [edit] it as comments can be deleted for numerous reasons. You might wish to be a bit more precise than "dedicated vps I've bought from somewhere". I'm also unclear on whether you want to stream live video or recorded video.  You migth find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893499/how-to-stream-desktop-and-audio-with-ffmpeg-in-youtube) or [this](https://www.dacast.com/blog/how-to-broadcast-live-stream-using-ffmpeg/) to provide useful alternatives and/or perhaps be educational

Comment: did you ever find a fix? I have same problem on 18.04