# Scheduled recording ffmpeg 14.04 with timer

Tags: alsa, ffmpeg, audio-recording, desktop-recording, video-recording

How do I set up a scheduled recording that stops after a set time with sound and video on 14.04? I want to record something 6 hours ahead that lasts 1 hour. 
It is really important that the video and sound are in top quality, and that the video quality does not decrease from the original stream. 
My screen is 1366x736.

I want to actually record from a m3u stream (iptv), but if that isn't possible then I can capture the screen instead.

And a question about recording the desktop if recording the m3u stream directly isn't possible: Does the audio of the pc have to be on while recording to get sound on the video?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One method for one-time scheduling is the [`at`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) command.

1. Enter the scheduled time:

   ```
   at 4:00 PM
   ```
2. Then a prompt will appear where you enter the command to be run:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.m3u -c copy -t 01:00:00 output.foo
   ```

   - The `-c copy` option will enable [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode which will preserve the quality because it will just re-mux instead of additionally encoding.
   - The `-t 01:00:00` option will set the duration to one hour. `ffmpeg` will then quit after one hour.
3. Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to save the command.

If this is to be a regularly scheduled event then you could use a cronjob instead.

As for desktop recording see:

- [Capturing ONLY desktop audio with ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/59378) (via PulseAudio)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: ALSA](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a shell script like this:

```
runtime_in_sec=3600
wait_time_in_sec=3600*6
sleep $wait_time_in_sec
ffmpeg <the options and the file> &  # alternatively use `avconv` instead of ffmpeg
PID=$!
sleep $runtime_in_sec
kill -9 $PID
```

If you wanted to set the exact hour, I would rather use a small python script or even just the ipython interpreter, because working with date and time is a lot easier.
I would for example use `time.monotonic()` for simple calculations with seconds...