# Up-to-date method to stream to Ubuntu from Terminal

Tags: 16.10, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

**I would like to stream from Ubuntu to Twitch in a lightweight manner from Terminal.**

I have tried https://gist.github.com/brodul/3178114 however I get a green screen when I go to my Twitch stream. There is no error output; everything seems fine except for a few errors.

This is not a duplicate question because the newest version of this question is 3 years old and no longer applicable.

I've tried running the following script:

```
STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)   # This is your streamkey

ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 60 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default
  -c:v libx264 -preset fast -b:v 4500k -bufsize 9000k -maxrate 5000k -g 120
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv "rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAMKEY"
```

however I run into the following error:

```
me@me:~$ ./start_stream.sh
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1516751285.842006, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 60 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, pulse, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1516751285.857784, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
./start_stream.sh: line 4: -c:v: command not found
./start_stream.sh: line 5: -pix_fmt: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 60 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default \
  -c:v libx264 -preset fast -b:v 4500k -bufsize 9000k -maxrate 5000k -g 120 \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv "rtmp://foo/your_stream_key"
```

- View the console output during the encoding process. If the output fps is lower than `-framerate` then decrease `-framerate` and/or use a faster `-preset`. Use the slowest `-preset` that still provides the desired output frame rate.
- `-b:v` is roughly determined by `-video_size`. See *Figure 3* in [Recommended Encoding Settings for HTTP Live Streaming Media](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-SETTINGSFILES) for some suggested bitrates (but do experiment and see what works best for you). `-bufsize` is determined by `-b:v`. In this example a 2 second buffer is used so `-bufsize` is 2x `-b:v`.
- `-g` should be 2x `-framerate`.
- If you get "`The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it`" then your `ffmpeg` is ancient and you should update instead of using `-strict -2`. The FFmpeg AAC encoder has been improved and is no longer considered experimental, but your version lacks these improvements. The easiest method to update is to [download a recent `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and move it to `/usr/local/bin` (or `~/bin` but you'll need to re-login or run `source ~/.profile` for it to work).

Also see:

- [x11grab video input device documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab)
- [pulse audio input device documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/H.264)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for Streaming Sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites)
- [Capturing desktop audio with ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/59378)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put one command on multiple lines. You get errors like this if you do:

```
./start_stream.sh: line 4: -c:v: command not found
./start_stream.sh: line 5: -pix_fmt: command not found
```

You need to put `\` on the end of each line where the next line is a continuation of this line, like this:

```
STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)   # This is your streamkey

ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 60 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default \
  -c:v libx264 -preset fast -b:v 4500k -bufsize 9000k -maxrate 5000k -g 120 \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv "rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAMKEY"
```

You also need to change `$STREAMKEY` to match the underscore in the middle of `STREAM_KEY` at the beginning.