# How to Record Audio from Application

Tags: sound, ffmpeg

I am trying to record my screen and the audio from my speakers using ffmpeg. This works fine on my tower PC with Ubuntu 18.04, but does not work using my thinkpad.

On the tower PC, this works fine using `https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop` (from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop ). But if I use the laptop, the same command records the sound from my microphone, which leads to heavily decreased sound quality.

`arecord -l` returns

```
arecord -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (CAPTURE) ****
Karte 3: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

and `aplay -l` returns:

```
aplay -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 2: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 2: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 2: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 2: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 2: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 3: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

Trying to set input like with `ffmpeg -video_size 1368x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -ac 2 output.mkv` (so `hw:0,0` which should in my opinition be the default device) results in an error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
[alsa @ 0x55931414d3e0] cannot open audio device hw:0,0 (No such file or directory)
```

If I use https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA#Recordaudiofromanapplication, so call `sudo modprobe snd-aloop pcm_substreams=1`, add

```
# .asoundrc
pcm.!default { type plug slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0" }
```

to `/etc/asound.conf`, change my output device to so loopback via the settings GUI and run `ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 out.wav` it records the audio perfectly correct. But if I run `ffmpeg -video_size 1368x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 output.mkv`, it just records the screen and some very rare small noises.

Is there a workaround for this, or is there another way to record my screen and the audio?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is the accepted answer from [Capturing ONLY desktop audio with ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682144/capturing-only-desktop-audio-with-ffmpeg) : Install `pavucontrol`, start recording with `ffmpeg -video_size 1280x1024 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -vcodec mpeg2video  -thread_queue_size 512 -ac 2 -t 02:00:00 -i default` (or whatever), go to `pavucontrol`, choose Recorings and change `Lavf56.15.102` (or whatever) to `Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo`. Worked for me.

I'll accept an answer which is able to do this without using `pavucontrol` for change of recording every restart.

Answer (score 0):

A very useful answer can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489522

Translated to your case, it might read as follows:

```
A="$(pacmd list-sources | grep -PB 1 "analog.*monitor>" | head -n 1 | perl -pe 's/.* //g')"
ffmpeg -video_size 1280x1024 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -vcodec mpeg2video -thread_queue_size 512 -ac 2 -t 02:00:00 -i "$A"
```