# FFmpeg streaming to youtube help needed for kids radio project

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-mate, youtube, raspberrypi, streaming

I have tried many codes but not one was fit for my needs so i am asking now for help, i have a video that i want to stream (with no audio on it) and desktop audio from the Pi (running Ubuntu Mate 16.04) as i would play the mp3's on vlc (or any other sugestions are welcome as i would use vlc only because it has repeat and shufle)

The kids radio stream is already live but as its a non profit project my Desktop windows mashine is eating to much money by running 24/7 so i got me the Pi3b+ for this job.

Thanks in advance

Ivan

Happy Pi Owner

Comment: update with this code i got the stream running with low CPU usage : $ ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i /home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4 -c copy -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX will try to implement the desktop audio now...

Comment: You could try [pavucontrol](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/59378) if you're using pulseaudio.

Comment: have pavucontrol installed  but cant get the code to run...

Comment: ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -f pulse -i default -y flv -ar 11025  -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k ouput.mp3  -stream_loop -1 -i /home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4 -c copy -f flv  -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX and i get this error [NULL @ 0x12e7c20] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'flv'
flv: Invalid argument

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i /home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4 -f pulse -i default -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, No errors but no sound on youtube, any idea? Here is a SS https://imgur.com/a/VcRAE3m

Comment: Also have the same issue (forgot to mention it) with the loop not working stoped after video ended... Here is the result. [pulse @ 0x10b9980] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame= 2144 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4295kB time=00:01:12.26 bitrate= 486.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
video:4182kB audio:18kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.237897%
[aac @ 0xfbbd60] Qavg: 65536.000

Comment: UPDATED CODE: '' ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i /home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video.mp4 -c copy -fflags +genpts  -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-XXXX''

Stream works, video file and desktop audio is streaming just cant get the video file to loop any ideas?
ffmpeg version 3.2.12

Comment: Upgrade your ffmpeg.

Comment: Update fixed the issue, needed to compile new ffmpeg with alsa support.

Comment: I got it to auto start on boot (if power failure), but i have one more barrier i cant find out how to do it, that is if the internet connection drops and ffmpeg stream stops how to reconnect it automatically? `ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video720p.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-xxx`

Comment: Since you found a solution to the original question I recommend making an answer here that addresses that original question. The "how to reconnect it automatically" should be a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming the file in a loop with desktop audio to youtube works. Thanks to all!

```
ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video720p.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-xxxx
```

ffmpeg version 4.1, if you have a older ffmpeg version the loop command may not work...