# How Can I Record System Audio and Send it to a Named Pipe on a Headless System?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg

I've got a named pipe at `~/audio/stream` that I want to send a copy of all my system audio to. The other side of this pipe is being read by a docker container and played using `aplay`. I know the other side is working since I can use `ffmpeg` to play audio into the pipe. I tried using `arecord` to get system audio, but I got no output on the other side. I'm not sure how to capture system audio and send it to a named pipe with `ffmpeg`. I'd like to capture it in a 44100hz, 16 bits, 2 channels format.

How can I capture system audio and send it to this named pipe?

Comment: See [Capturing ONLY desktop audio with ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/) and also see the comment about `pactl list soruces`. Then do something like `ffmpeg -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor -f wav ~/audio/stream`

Comment: @llogan I tried that, but it didn't seem to capture any audio