# How to use "at" command in shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, audio-recording

I would like to use audio-recorder for recording. It should start recording at a certain time and stop after hours.

Comment: So what's the problem? You use it exactly like in command-line, see `man at`. Please [edit] and clarify: What did you try? What behaviour did you experience? What's wrong?

Comment: An example would create a job that starts your recorder then one that switches it off some hours later and also removes that previous at job.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're talking about [this software](https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages), however it does provide only very limited command-line options. If you want to record audio from command-line or in a script you better stick to command-line programs – I'm essentially using [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/850174/507051) here. For this to work you might need to install some packages, run `sudo apt install pulseaudio-utils lame` to be sure.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sink="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
echo 'f=$(date +%F_%R)_rec.mp3;timeout "'$2'" parec -d "'$sink'".monitor|lame -r -V0 - $f'|
at "$1"
```

You need to adjust the value of `sink` to your system, `pacmd list-sinks|grep name:` shows it enclosed in `<>` (don't copy those!). After that make the script executable with `chmod +x SCRIPTNAME` and run it as e.g. `/path/to/SCRIPTNAME 10pm 30m` to record for 30 minutes starting at 10pm. The recording will be saved in the directory where you run the script as e.g. `2017-12-17_10:00_rec.mp3` for a recording that started at this date and time. If you want to change that, replace `$(date +%F_%R)_rec.mp3` in the script.

#### Example run

```
$ ./test.sh 10:00 10m
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1 at Sun Dec 17 10:00:00 2017
$ atq
1      Sun Dec 17 10:00:00 2017 a dessert
$ atrm 1
$ atq
$
```

As you can see, you can use `atq` to display and `atrm` to remove a pending job.

#### Time and duration format

As for the time format see `man at`, especially:

> At (…) accepts times of the form
>          HH:MM to run a job at a specific time of day.  (If that time is already past, the next day is  assumed.)   You
>          may  also  specify  midnight, noon, or teatime (4pm) and you can have a time-of-day suffixed with AM or PM for
>          running in the morning or the evening.  You can also say what day the job will be run, by giving a date in the
>          form month-name day with an optional year, or giving a date of the form MMDD[CC]YY, MM/DD/[CC]YY, DD.MM.[CC]YY
>          or [CC]YY-MM-DD.  The specification of a date must follow the specification of the time of day.  You can  also
>          give times like now + count time-units, where the time-units can be minutes, hours, days, or weeks and you can
>          tell at to run the job today by suffixing the time with today and to run the job  tomorrow  by  suffixing  the
>          time with tomorrow.

As for the duration format see `man timeout`, especially:

> DURATION is a floating point number with an optional suffix: 's' for seconds (the default), 'm'  for  minutes,
>          'h' for hours or 'd' for days.