# Audio-recorder not recording in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, audio-recording

Had Audio-Recorder working in earlier versions. Installed Ubuntu 18.04 and installed Audio-Recorder. There is no audio being recorded. Both "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo (Audio Output)" or "System's default device" sources tried with same result. The level indicator at the top of the window also shows nothing. Can't find anything relevant with a Google search. Any advise please.
Thanks
Tony

Comment: I have just installed Audio-Recorder on Linux Mint 18.03 on the same machine and have the same problem. Is the problem Audio-Record, my pc - or me?

Comment: Returning to Ubuntu and trying to record using Audacity as per the instructions here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers,  have the same problem.

Comment: Many more hours later - the volume levels look right in alphamixer : looking at the HDA Intel PCH card all the volume levels look ok. Looking at the pavucontrol  Recording window the relevant application name appears when I start recording in either Audacity or Audio-recorder. Recording with Audacity with the HDA Intel PCH card selected for input then there is a very, very low level of distorted sound being recorded. (The speaker and headphone sound from the pc has no problems). Don't know what else to try.

Comment: Tried Linux Mint again and for no apparent reason it now works with Audio-Recorder, but not Audacity. Doesn't anybody have any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem in ubuntu 18.04.4 in my Dell optiplex 790 desktop as you described.
I solved this problem by doing following steps in Terminal:

1. Install PulseAudio Volume Control:
   sudo apt install pavucontrol
2. Install Audio Recorder:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audio-recorder/ppa
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install audio-recorder
3. Open Audio Recorder choose the source (I choose Rhythmbox), and Format you want to save the file (I choose .mp3). and Start recording.
4. Open PulseAudio Volume Control, to make sure the following choices:
   Playback Tag -> system Sounds not mute, 
   Out put Devices Tag -> Port (Line Out),
   Configuration -> Profile (Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input)

By now, you may not hear anything from your speaker, but sound from Rhythmbox are successfully recorded to the file. 
You may double check the file by replay with the change of Profile back to Analog Stereo Duplex/Output.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this other answer https://askubuntu.com/a/229365/294611
It is written for Audacity, but will work for Audio Recorder also. If you need more clarification please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Edward Torvalds. I've been through your suggestion but the problem remains. On the P.A. Volume Control screen when I start recording in Audacity I get "ALSA Plugin Audacity: ALSA Capture" appearing but there is no "from" following it as appears on your screenshot.

Comment: @Tony I am having the same issue. you should start recording the audio and then open the active applications tab in pavucontrol and then switch the audio source. It worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks, but what is the "active applications tab"?

Comment: @Tony sorry, my bad. Recording tab, it shows currently recording application