# How to record in .opus with Audio Recorder or via CLI?

Tags: sound, audio-recording

I want to record an audio stream with Audio Recorder in .opus format or via the command line.  I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers/865819#865819) and tried the alias suggestion provided as the last answer but unfortunately it gave me an error: `Failed to parse the argument for --monitor-stream` and Xen2050's question relating to the same problem was never answered.  I then tried to see if I could get Audio Recorder to record in .opus with `opusenc --raw - $(xdg-user-dir MUSIC)/recording-$(date +"%F_%H-%M-%S").opus` and `audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=2 !libopus name=enc quality=0.5 ! oggmux` but it gives me an error that it needs the GStreamer opus plugin.  Despite installing via apt `gstreamer1.0-plugins-*`, `opus-tools`, and `libopus0` it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Under AudioRecorder I use:

- Title: Opus 48khz 32kbs
- File extension: opus
- Command:
  `audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=2 ! opusenc name=enc bitrate=32000 ! oggmux`

These are working in Lubuntu 20.04, although there seems to be hard coded rate and not fully libopus working.

Comment: Despite https://wiki.xiph.org/Opus_Recommended_Settings, I've found that when I try to specify single-digit changes to e.g., "ffmpeg -i ... -b:a 17k -acode libopus ..." it only encodes at certain bit rates per mediainfo.