# Ubuntu - Other people can hear whatever I play during call

Tags: 20.04, sound, echo

During Google Meet call, other people can hear whatever I can from my computer without me sharing my screen. It can be Youtube, FB video from Chrome or song I play on the Spotify app, whatever kind of sound I play. How can I fix this, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

For more details, I'm using a headset with only 1 input jack for both sound and mic. I connect this headset through a cable looks like below. It has 2 jacks on 1 side which connect to my PC for sound and mic. The other side would connect to the input jack of the headset. [image][image]

Comment: Install and run `pavucontrol`, at "Recording" tab, check what is the input source for Google Meet when you have it open. You should be able to change input to microphone.

Comment: Are you playing the sound over speakers?

Comment: @pLumo I can see the microphone receiving something even in the sound settings, not something related to external apps.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: In Ubuntu you can set the input and output source for each program separately, so even if you can see the microphone working in the sound settings, it doesn't mean anything. `pavucontrol` is not an "external" app but a more sophisticated sound setting program compared to the default one where you can change that.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1320217